# How to show the one point compactification of a cylinder isn't a manifold.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I'm trying to show that the one-point compactification of a cylinder $C^*$ = C$\cup${$\infty$} isn't a manifold.

The way I'm trying to show this is if $C^*$ is a manifold then if I take a neighborhood U of {$\infty$} there should be a subneighborhood V of U such that V\ {$\infty$} is connected. And then I'd have to show that  V\ {$\infty$} is disconnected.

But I'm not sure if V\ {$\infty$} disconnected or not, my intuition says it should be I just can't prove it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If one takes a connected neighborhood of a point in any $n$-manifold, $n \geq 2$ and removes a point, then the punctured neighborhood is always connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $S$ be a circle around $C$; $U=C^*\setminus S$ is an open nbhd of $\infty$. Show that no open nbhd of $\infty$ contained in $U$ can be connected, because it must meet both components of $C\setminus S$. Remember that open nbhds of $\infty$ have complements that are compact subsets of $C$.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say components of C\S, do you mean something like (x,0)~(x,1) for all x in (0,1)?

Comment: @Tumnum: I’m not sure what you mean. I mean the two connected components of $C\setminus S$, each of which is homeomorphic to $C$.

Comment: Sorry I should've worded that better. I just was using a definition from Munkres that says equivalence classes are called the components of X.

Comment: @Tumnum: You have to specify the equivalence relation in order for that to make sense. In this case the equivalence relation is that $x\sim y$ iff there is a connected subset of $C\setminus S$ containing both $x$ and $y$. At a guess, you were thinking of the equivalence relation used to define $C$, which is unrelated.

Comment: Sorry I just got one more question. We're "slicing" the cylinder in half when we remove the circle S, so C\S is a union of two disjoint sets?

Comment: @Tumnum: That’s right. Think of it as slicing through the ‘equator’ of the cylinder.